# How to get Optional<String> from String? and String in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have overridden a function in Kotlin that returns an `Optional<String>`.  How do I convert `String?` and `String` types into `Optional<String>`?

**Example:**

```
override fun getCurrentAuditor(): Optional<String> {
    val userName = SecurityUtils.currentUserLogin
    return userName ?: SYSTEM_ACCOUNT
}
```

From the above example:

`userName` is a `String?`

`SYSTEM_ACCOUNT` is a `String`

I'm getting errors on the return statement that both variables are not `Optional<String>` types.

Comment: Can you tell me why you want to do this. Kotlin has better way to handle null values using String? (Kotlin optionals).

Comment: @swapnil he explained that in the first sentence he wrote

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just create one that wrap the string value, in your case:

```
override fun getCurrentAuditor(): Optional<String> {
    val userName = SecurityUtils.currentUserLogin
    return Optional.of(userName ?: SYSTEM_ACCOUNT)
}
```